# How to include R snippet code from external file into Quarto document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, quarto

Wondering how to include [r](/questions/tagged/r) snippet code from external file into [quarto](/questions/tagged/quarto) document.

1. The following code using  `knitr::read_chunk()` works fine however, depends on [knitr](/questions/tagged/knitr).

   ```
   knitr::read_chunk("Ch02.R")
   ```
2. The following code using [quarto](/questions/tagged/quarto) code runs without any error but does not work as expected.

   ```
   #| eval: true
   #| output: false
   #| file: Ch02.R
   ```

Wondering if there is any alternative in [quarto](/questions/tagged/quarto) for `knitr::read_chunk()`.

Answer (score 8):

## Option 1: include

If you want to [`include`](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/includes.html) other code snippets, you could only use qmd files when using include:

> Computational includes work only in .qmd files

Let's create a simple qmd file called **create_dataframe.qmd** which add a column to mtcars:

````
---
title: "Create dataframe"
---

```{r}
# Create data file 
mtcars$new_col = sample(c(0,1), nrow(mtcars), replace = TRUE)
```
````

Now you can include that file in your main.qmd file like this:

````
---
title: "Document"
---

{{< include create_dataframe.qmd >}}

Let's check if extra columns is created:

```{r}
# View dataframe
head(mtcars)
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the column created in the create_dataframe.qmd file is now in your main file.

---

## Option 2: file in chunk

You could also the `file` option in your chunk like this. You have to make sure it evaluates the code using `eval` like this:

````
---
title: "Document"
---

Let's check if extra columns is created:

```{r}
#| echo: true
#| eval: true 
#| file: create_dataframe.R
```

```{r}
# View dataframe
head(mtcars)
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see the new column is also in the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I got from your answer is that `knitr::read_chunk("Ch02.R")` is only the solution to include `R` snippet code from external file into `Quarto` document.

Comment: Hi @MYaseen208, Please see my edited answer with another option!

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `source` to just run the valid R code or use `file` to include the script as a chunk and evaluate

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

## Include will interpret the content as markdown:

{{< include Chu1.R >}}


## Source will evaluate:

```{r}
#| echo: false
source("Chu1.R")
```


##  file will echo and evaluate

```{r,file = "Chu1.R"}

```
````

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `include` directive.

For example,

```
{{< include Ch02.R >}}
```

More details at https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/includes.html